# file not adding to DistributedCache

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am running Hadoop on my local system, in eclipse environment.

I tried to put a local file from  workspace into the distributed cache in driver function as:

```
DistributedCache.addCacheFile(new Path(
            "/home/hduser/workspace/myDir/myFile").toUri(), conf);
```

but when I tried to access it from Mapper, it returns null.
Inside mapper, I checked to see whether file cached.

```
System.out.println("Cache: "+context.getConfiguration().get("mapred.cache.files"));
```

it prints "null", also

```
Path[] cacheFilesLocal = DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFiles(context.getConfiguration());
```

returns `null`.

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you can only add files to the Distributed Cache from HDFS not local file system. So the Path doesn't exist. Put the file on HDFS and use the HDFS path to refer to it when adding to the DistributedCache.

See [DistributedCache](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/filecache/DistributedCache.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Add file:// in the path when you add cache file

DistributedCache.addCacheFile(new Path( "file:///home/hduser/workspace/myDir/myFile"), conf);

Answer (score -1):

Try this

DRIVER Class

```
Path p = new Path(your/file/path);
FileStatus[] list = fs.globStatus(p);
for (FileStatus status : list) {
     /*Storing file to distributed cache*/
  DistributedCache.addCacheFile(status.getPath().toUri(), conf);
}
```

Mapper class

```
public void setup(Context context) throws IOException{
        /*Accessing data in file */
        Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
        URI[] cacheFiles = DistributedCache.getCacheFiles(conf);
        /* Accessing 0 th cached file*/
        Path getPath = new Path(cacheFiles[0].getPath());
        /*Read data*/
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs.open(getPath)));
        String setupData = null;
        while ((setupData = bf.readLine()) != null) {
            /*Print file content*/
            System.out.println("Setup Line "+setupData);
        }
       bf.close();
    }

public void map(){

}
```

Comment: getCacheFiles() returns the original path. Not the local path for the copied file. This solution bypasses distributed cache itself